# WorkflowPostponeThreshold configuration for SharePoint 2010 Workflow

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-server, workflow

I am trying to improve the performance of the workflows in a SharePoint 2010 environment.

I increased the Workflow Postpone Threshold value from 15 to 40 using the below command

```
Set-SPFarmConfig -WorkflowPostponeThreshold 40
```

It seemed to have improved workflow performance in general. However, I was wondering if there is an upper limit to this value. I was reading about this attribute [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits-0) but it doesn't specify an upper threshold value

Also are there any other ways to improve the workflow performance in SharePoint 2010? I tried the below tweaks

```
WorkflowPostponeThreshold  - 200
WorkflowEventDeliveryTimeout  - 20
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits?redirectedfrom=MSDN#ContentDB): Increasing this limit increases the throughput of starting and completing workflow tasks but also increases load against the content database and system resources.

So I think there is no upper limit for the parameter -WorkflowPostponeThreshold.

Besides, the three parameters to improve the workflow Performance.

1.Increase Throttle Size

2.Increase Default Batch Size

3.Increase Timeout

Reference: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/improving-workflow-performance-in-sharepoint-2010